# Numeric data file sort write Issue

Tags: java, arrays

I have a data file with the entries (5 numbers per line:

```
8,1,3,7,9 
2,4,7,10,11 
9,99,4,7,3 
5,1,2,3,17
```

The complete data file is extremely large but has similar data throughout.
I am trying to read the data line by line from the input file, 
Sort the numbers on that line,
Then write the sorted numbers to a new output file.

Rather than storing the entire input file into an array or memory, I want to only store the numbers for each line, one line at a time, sort it, and write those sorted numbers to the next line in the output file.  I have come up with an initial way to read and write the smaller data set to a different file, but its writing the array which appears within braces such as `[ 1, 3, 7, 8, 9]` instead of as `1, 3, 7, 8, 9`  .  When I figure out what the correct, more efficient way is, I was also planning on creating a seperate class just for the sorting and would read one line at a time from the data file, pass it to the seperate class which would sort it and write it to the output datafile.  How can I correctly input each line one at a time into the array, sort it, and write it to the new output datafile?

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.Arrays;

    public class Soup {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File dir = new File(".");

        String source = dir.getCanonicalPath() + File.separator + "Code.txt";
        String dest = dir.getCanonicalPath() + File.separator + "Dest.txt";

        File fin = new File(source);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fin);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(dest, true);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

        String aLine = null;
        while ((aLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            //Process each line and add output to Dest.txt file
            //Arrays.sort(aLine);

            String[] strings = aLine.split(",");
            int[] numbers = new int[strings.length];

            for (int i=0; i < numbers.length; i++)
            {
              numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(strings[i]);


            }
            Arrays.sort(numbers);

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));



            //for(int k=0; k < numbers.length; k++)
                //out.writeObject(numbers[k]);


            //out.write(aLine);
            out.write(Arrays.toString(numbers));
            //out.write(numbers
            //out.write((numbers));
            out.newLine();
        }

        // do not forget to close the buffer reader
        in.close();

        // close buffer writer
        out.close();
```

Comment: and what is your question? Creating an own class for sort doesn't change efficiency. If speed is your concern, and you know its always five numbers, you may reuse the int[5] array instead of recreating it each time.

Answer (score 1):

Your Arrays.toString(numbers) adds the brackets. Just replace the brackets with an empty string before you write it to the file -

```
out.write(Arrays.toString(numbers).replaceAll("\[|\]", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 out.write(Arrays.toString(numbers).replaceAll("\[|\]", ""));    does not work, error:    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(Unknown Source)
```

Also, I am trying to figure out a better method of performing the sort and write task, Im sure my code is not efficient and am looking for a more efficient way to accomplish the task.  I am open to suggestions.

Comment: you're telling me that you can't use replaceAll on a java string? I can use it and it works fine. what version of java are you running? also your sort method is as fast as possible, the built in sort is O(n*logn) which is plenty fast enough.

Comment: out.write(Arrays.toString(numbers).replaceAll("\[|\]", "")); 
Invalid escape sequence(valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r "\' \\)

Comment: use my current one i posted, yours clearly do not have the \ like the one i posted. you are using "[|]" i am using "\\[|\\]"